# Entity Framework query using TimeZoneInfo cannot be translated to SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, timezone

I am working with time zones in my .NET application. I followed the best practices regarding time zones according to Microsoft (link below):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973825(v=msdn.10)

Here you can read that the best option is to store the time zone in the database with the time in that time zone and perform calculations transforming it to UTC. I was trying to filter the records based on the date using the following piece of code:

```
var result = ContextClassObject.Entity
                               .Where(e => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(e.Date) > DateTime.UtcNow)
                               .ToList();
```

I get the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: „The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(a => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(a.Date) > DateTime.UtcNow)' could not be translated. Additional information:
> Translation of method 'System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

I think it means that my query cannot be translated to a SQL query so I have to tell it directly how to translate it or materialize the data and then filter it in C#, which I don't want to do because it's gonna be slower than SQL Server could do it and premature materialization isn't a good thing to do.

Is there a way to make it work without mapping the function to a SQL query directly which would be quite complicated for a simple operation? Should I just store any DateTime in UTC, which is supposed to be a good method too and save myself the trouble?

Below is the example row of a database. The date is in the time zone, which id is stored right next to it:

[image: Example of a row in the database]

I have tried storing it with DateTimeOffset like that:

[image]

Then the query below produces the same error:

```
TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Alaskan Standard Time");
            DateTime userDate = new DateTime(2022, 09, 27, 11, 58, 12);
            DateTime dateInUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(userDate, userTimeZone);

            var result = await _dataContext.DateEntity
                .Where(e => e.Date.Add(e.Date.Offset) > dateInUTC)
                .ToListAsync();
```

I have tried different methods to add or subtract the offset and found out that only accessing the Offset property of the DateTimeOffset class cannot be translated. Using raw numbers works just fine.

Comment: You know that "best practices" document is from 2004, right, and very clearer states in the banner *"We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported."*

Comment: I understand that the document may be outdated. I am not sure what to look for in the Microsoft Lifecycle Policy to be honest. Can you elaborate as to what am I supposed to find?

Comment: Hi.  Please tell us more about what the field is used for.  For example, is it storing a person's birthday? Or is it the time a transaction took place?  Something else?  (There is no one-size-fits-all solution to date time issues.)

Comment: Well, it was supposed to store a date when a job offer expires for example (it is just my exercise and getting to know time zones in C#). When someone adds a job offer, the date when it ends is stored according to the time in his time zone. When someone views it, it should be modified to the time in his time zone.

Comment: I am guessing that I would write a script that gets the users time zone, pass it to the right endpoint and then modify the date using the information about the users time zone and the time zone the offer was created in.

Comment: Why are you storing the time zone ID of the person who *added* the job offer.  Isn't the time of the person receiving the offer more relevant?  Do offers really expire at `14:34:12` (to the second) like shown in your example, or are you just doing something like now + 24 hrs?  Any reason why you didn't just store a `DateTimeOffset`?  (SQL Server has an equivalent `datetimeoffset` data type for the field.)

Comment: Just to be clear - it would be bad to store it as you showed, because the only way to query would be to evaluate and convert every row in your table at time of query.  The more data you added, the slower it would take.  An index wouldn't help in this case, because you'd have to use something like SQL Server's `AT TIME ZONE` on every value in the table.

Comment: As to your second comment you are right. I might have done it wrong and that's why I can't get the result that I want. For the first comment - I was storing the time zone ID because I would need two time zone IDs (the one who added and the one viewing the job offer) and both would be relevant. 14:32:12 was just an example, but turns out it brought some confusion, it was just some date I inputed as an example. I am going to try to do it with DateTimeOffset now and see if it works, but if I am imagining it right, I think it will.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work that easily. I cannot access the Offset property just how I explained in my edited question. I could store DateTime and Offset separately or just store the date in UTC to begin with. Those are the options that I came up with. Have you found a way to make DateTimeOffset work that I didn't think of?